# Fake proof that $0=1$ using $\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and integration by parts

Tags: integration, fake-proofs

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$I saw, in a [series of joke proofs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkzQf5WAAbg&t=365s) that Santa Claus exists, the following:

We want to evaluate the indefinite integral of: $$\int\color{green}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{\d x}{x}}$$

Using the standard IBP, I consider $\color{green}{u}$ and $\color{red}{\d v}$:

$$\int\color{green}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{\d x}{x}}=\color{green}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}\cdot\color{red}{\ln x}-\int\color{red}{\ln x}\color{green}{\left(-\frac{1}{x\cdot\ln^2x}\right)\,\d x}=1+\int\frac{1}{\ln x}\cdot\frac{\d x}{x}$$

From which we "conclude" that $0=1$ by subtracting the indefinite integral from both sides.

A simple substitution concludes that in fact the indefinite integral is $\ln\ln x$, but I'm really curious where the fallacy is here; I think I've found it, but would like confirmation. I do not see any division by zero errors, the chain rule is correctly applied.

Going back to the derivation of IBP, the fallacy possibly lies in the fact that $u v$ is a constant function with zero derivative, so I need to be careful with constants of integration, i.e. include $C=-1$.

Is that right? And in general, if $uv$ is a constant function, will IBP create silly expressions like this?

Comment: there is no reason why the constants of integration on the left and right-hand side should be equal. So, "subtracting them" does not even make sense.

Comment: @Matematleta That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Yes.  This is a good argument to include "$+C$" for indefinite integrals.

Comment: Also try adding limits on the integrals to have $C=0$ and  see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An indefinite integral denotes the set of all antiderivatives of its integrand. What you've proven is$$\left\{f|f^\prime=\tfrac{1}{x\ln x}\right\}=\{1+g|g^\prime=\tfrac{1}{x\ln x}\}.$$That these two sets of functions are the same implies a function is an element of one iff it's an element of the other, but doesn't say which *other* elements the second set has.

Comment: (+1) nicely explained, this is quite a common fallacy!